# NameError py2app in modulegraph

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I'm trying to use py2app to create a standalone application of mac. When I`m using the alias mode everything work fine, but when I try to

```
python setup.py py2app
```

I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 21, in <module>
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/robert/Envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 659, in run
    self._run()
  File "/Users/robert/Envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 865, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/Users/robert/Envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 943, in run_normal
    self.process_recipes(mf, filters, flatpackages, loader_files)
  File "/Users/robert/Envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 824, in process_recipes
    rval = check(self, mf)
  File "/Users/robert/Envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py2app/recipes/virtualenv.py", line 86, in check
    mf._scan_code(co, m)
  File "/Users/robert/Envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1543, in _scan_code
    self._scan_bytecode(co, m)
  File "/Users/robert/Envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1570, in _scan_bytecode
    n = len(code)
NameError: name 'code' is not defined
```

My version of Python 3.5, py2app 0.10, module graph 0.13. Has anyone encountered a similar one, and how I can solve it?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

This issue will be fixed in moudulegraph 0.14

If you can't wait you can pull from the repo any point after this commit:
https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/modulegraph/commits/32c6c60f9dcdb106219a1476218e0d364cb11255